# why row class occupy only about 50% width in bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <title>Collapsible sidebar using Bootstrap 3</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style5.css">
</head>
<body>

  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid ">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-1 bg-light">
            <button type="button" id="leftSidebarCollapse" class="navbar-btn d-sm-block d-md-none">
             <span></span>
             <span></span>
             <span></span>
           </button>
         </div> 

         <div class="col-sm-11 ">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown
                  </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- Sidebar Holder -->
  <nav id="leftSidebar">
    <h2 class="main_topic">Bootstrap Sidebar</h2>

    <ul class="list-unstyled components">

      <li class="active">
        <a href="#">About</a>


      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </nav>

  <!-- Page Content Holder -->
  <div id="content">


    <h2>Collapsible Sidebar Using Bootstrap 3</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <div class="line"></div>

    <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <div class="line"></div>

    <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <div class="line"></div>

    <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>





<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#leftSidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
      $('#leftSidebar').toggleClass('active');
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I wrapped class `row` within class `container-fluid` and according to bootstrap 4 the `row` div should occupy 100% width by default. Now it occupies only about 50% width. Here is the screenshot:
[image]

I tried to remove my custom css `style5.css` so that I can damn sure this strange issue is not due to my custom css. Please correct me and I am apologizing if this question doesn't deserve a standard to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a Bootstrap 4 common problem, you can find some issues on the Bootstrap Github repository referring to the `.row` not getting 100% width. For example there's a problem with [.list-group with .row inside](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21610).

You can see there's another user in the issue saying `.container > .row` inside a navbar doesn't get a 100% width `.row` .

We should wait until Bootstrap team fix it, for now an easy solution is to add `w-100` to your `row` class like:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid ">
    <div class="row w-100">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

There's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wjZmBW) with the change.

Answer (score 0):

**The grid row & cols shouldn't be used inside the Bootstrap 4 Navbar**

Read about the [supported 4.x Navbar content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/#supported-content). The Navbar uses flexbox which will by default shrink the content which is what's happening with the `.row` in this case.